# reset index every 5th row - Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle

How can I make index column start over after reaching 5th row? I can't do that with a window function as there are no groups, I just need an index with max number of 5 like this:

| date | index |
| --- | --- |
| 01.01.21 | 1 |
| 02.01.21 | 2 |
| 03.01.21 | 3 |
| 04.01.21 | 4 |
| 05.01.21 | 5 |
| 06.01.21 | 1 |
| 07.01.21 | 2 |

and so on.

Appreciate any ideas.

Comment: If you want every fifth row (as your example also shows), why do you say **6th** in your title? More importantly - what does any of this have to do with **pl sql**? You obviously mean Oracle SQL; if you don't know what PL/SQL means, please don't refer to it - you are just confusing everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below solution for that purpose.

1. First, rank (***row_number*** analytic function)the rows in your table within inline view
2. Then, use again the ***row_number*** function with ***partition by*** clause to group the previously ranked rows by TRUNC((rnb - 1)/5)

```sql
SELECT t."DATE"
   , row_number()over(PARTITION BY TRUNC((rnb - 1)/5) ORDER BY rnb) as "INDEX"
FROM (
  select "DATE", row_number()OVER(ORDER BY "DATE") rnb
  from Your_table
) t
ORDER BY 1
;
```

[*demo on db<>fiddle*](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=bd0bc0483a6e976fcc021f7087880e1f)

Answer (score 1):

Your comment about using analytic functions is wrong; you ***can*** use analytic functions even when there are no "groups" (or "partitions"). Here you do need an analytic function, to ***order*** the rows (even if you don't need to *partition* them).

Here is a very simple solution, using just `row_number()`. Note the `with` clause, which is not part of the solution; I included it just for testing. In your real-life case, remove the `with` clause, and use your actual table and column names. The use of `mod(... , 5)` is pretty much obvious; it looks a little odd (subtracting 1, taking the modulus, then adding 1) because in Oracle we seem to count from 1 in all cases, instead of the much more natural counting from 0 common in other languages (like C).

Note that both `date` and `index` are reserved keywords, which shouldn't be used as column names. I used one common way to address that - I added an underscore at the end.

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.rr';

with
  sample_inputs (date_) as (
    select date '2021-01-01' from dual union all
    select date '2021-01-02' from dual union all
    select date '2021-01-03' from dual union all
    select date '2021-01-04' from dual union all
    select date '2021-01-05' from dual union all
    select date '2021-01-06' from dual union all
    select date '2021-01-07' from dual
  )
select date_, 1 + mod(row_number() over (order by date_) - 1, 5) as index_
from   sample_inputs
;

DATE_        INDEX_
-------- ----------
01.01.21          1
02.01.21          2
03.01.21          3
04.01.21          4
05.01.21          5
06.01.21          1
07.01.21          2
```

Comment: Ah... good. I forgot to subtract 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `MOD()` with `ROW_NUMBER()` to get the index you want. For example:

```
select date, 1 + mod(row_number() over(order by date) - 1, 5) as idx from t
```